# Using OpenRowSet with parametized file names

Tags: c#, sql, xml, dynamic-sql

I am trying to extract an XML file from a given location, however I will be getting that specific location in C# and needing to pass it into the sql script.

This is a snippet of my current code:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

DECLARE @filePath nvarchar(256) 

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\BimlFlex\BimlFlex.DatabaseContents.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Obviously I want to replace the hard coded path with @filepath (or a ?) but when i do so it says that it expects a string or a text_lex.

Then in c# i am hoping to do something like:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(...))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlServerParameter(0, "actual path from unzipping");
```

edit: I am going to use dynamic SQL for the openrowset portion like so:

```
DECLARE @OpenRowSetSql nvarchar(MAX)

SET @OpenRowSetSql =
'INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE()
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+ @filePath + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'

EXEC sp_executesql @OpenRowSetSql
```

now my question is:
 how do i load up the parameter in C#?

Comment: do a google search on the following to see the many examples on the internet `Stackoverflow FROM OPENROWSET`

Comment: Ok so i have figured out i need to make my OpenRowSet query into Dynamic sql, but then how do i load up the parameter in C#? 

this is my new query 
[here](http://pastebin.com/zGVDGc0v)

Comment: update your code I am not going to click on unknown links sorry edit the question and show your dynamic SQL here

Comment: done, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i figured out my answer.

If you are using a SqlConnection then you need to pass in the variable name as a parameter so it would be :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlServerParameter("@filePath", "actual path from unzipping");
```

however in an OleDbConnection, then you need to do something like

```
DECLARE @filePath nvarchar(256) 
SET @filePath = ?
```

in the sql...and then

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("0", "actual path from unzipping");
```

where 0 corresponds to the number variable (represented by a "?") it is from the top (starting at 0).